# What are some good homebrewing magazines?

Tags: beer, magazine, media

What is a great brewing magazine?

- Why do you like it?
- What does it do well?
- Why is it better than the others?

Comment: How do I make this a community wiki question?

Comment: I think you have to flag it to alert the admins.

Comment: I modified the question so it's easier to answer and made it wiki

Answer (score 3):

There are really only 2 magazines devoted to homebrewing...Zymurgy and Brew Your Own (BYO).  Both are pretty good, although I lean toward Zymurgy (disclaimer:I've written for both).  What Makes me prefer Zymurgy is partially that I think the articles are a bit better, but mainly that you get it by joining the American Homebrewers Association.  That means you support homebrewers and the AHA's legislative efforts.